# Tkinter buttons which require their command to return a value

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have an odd question about `tkinter` entry boxes:

I know that I can write

```
add_charge = tk.Button(self, text='Add Data', command=function)
```

and that if the function is dependent on parameters I can write it as

```
add_charge = tk.Button(self, text='Add Data', command=lambda: function(parameters)
```

but my issue is this, I have a function defined as this

```
def add_charge(x,y,i, data):
    """ x,y are locations if the charge, i is the value of charge, data is existing charges"""
    temp = data.append(Charge(x,y,i)) #Charge is a predefined class which creates the charge object
    return temp
```

What I need to do is save temp to a variable and replace the pre-existing data, but I can't figure out how to save the value that the function returns once the button has been pressed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can't. You will have to modify the function to change a global variable instead of returning the data. If you move to a class structure (like you should in all GUIs) then you can use instance variables instead of globals.

Comment: Also, `lambda` is known to cause a lot of bugs because beginners don't understand how it works. I highly recommend you use `functools.partial` or a normal function / method instead.

Comment: In your example you are already modifying a global. The return statement in your example is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commenters, I have established a workaround, instead of

```
def add_charge(x,y,i,data):
    temp = data.append(Charge(x,y,i))
    return temp
```

I can write

```
global charge_data
charge_data = []
```

Then later, I can write

```
def add_charge(x,y,i):
   charge_data.append(Charge(x,y,i))
```

Which allows me to effectively eliminate the need to store the result of the function.

Comment: You don't need `global charge_data`, already global variables don't need to be explicitly initiated using the `global` keyword.

Comment: @abccd I guess it's bad answer formatting, but the way my program is set up, I do have to explicitly create the variable because it is defined within a class.